# How do I set the default app for .ts files to Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, windows-10

I have a PC running Windows 10 Pro for Workstations, and currently Typescript files (extension .ts) open with Films & TV. I have gone into Settings > Choose default apps by file type, and change it to Visual Studio Code, but it does not change it. So far I have uninstalled Films & TV and switched off Windows Media Player but it still will not save my choice of default.
I have also tried this: navigate to a .ts file. Right click & select open with. Tick the box - Always use this app to open .ts files. Select Visual Studio Code & OK. It still does not change.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. It seems Windows 10 forces you to use a "media" application (such as VLC or Movies & TV). I'll post an answer if I find a solution

Answer (score 5):

You can change register values under 
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.ts` register entry into following:

```
ContentType text/plain
PerceivedType text
```

Then, system will allow you to change associated application as in other popular use cases (i.e. right click > properties > change...)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up removing the Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.ts key in regedit, then opening a .ts file with the "Open with ..." option. After that was able to open .ts files with my choosen program.

Answer (score 0):

Right click -> Properties -> Change button in "Opens With" -> select Visual Studio or VS Code.

Click on OK.  It should make the default program for TS extension.

Comment: That did not work. Opened the current file but did not change to default app.

Comment: In my "Open With" menu VSCode was alrady listed. Choosing this did not change the default app. But going through "Select other app..." I could again choose VSCode, but also check "Make this the default app for .ts files". That changed the default app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by,

Right Clicking a `.ts` file -> Hover over `Open With` -> Click `Choose Another App` -> Tick the `Always use this app to open .ts files` -> Select VsCode from the list of apps -> Click Ok.